# Force NSTextView to show ambiguous width characters as halfwidth

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, unicode, nstextview, unicode-normalization

[Ambiguous width Unicode characters](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/#ED6) are either halfwidth or fullwidth depending on the context (locale, font, surrounding characters).

How can I force `NSTextView` to always render ambiguous width characters as halfwidth? Is there some normalization algorithm that I should use? Ideally, there would be a configuration where I can set this.

Comment: There is a `CFMutableString` API for converting between full-width and half width. Perhaps you could apply it directly to your strings before passing them to `NSTextView`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/cfmutablestring/transform_identifiers_for_cfstringtransform?language=objc

Comment: If you need to convert user-entered texton the fly, perhaps you can put your string transformation code in the delegate methods of `NSTextView`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Nice find! It doesn’t work if there is no halfwidth character equivalent though. For example, `\u{a1}` is transformed to `\u{a1}`. :-(

Comment: I wonder if I can set ICU properties in Cocoa. If so, then I can set `East_Asian_Width` to `0` to configure a character as East-Asian neutral?

Comment: Nvm ICU does not allow one to modify properties at runtime: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/properties#TOC-Customization